# I have a bootstrap navbar that will not stay in-line with the button and search box - how do I make it in-line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, nav

```html
<nav id="NavbarMaster" class="navbar NavCompression">
  <!-- style="min-height:100px;" -->
  <div id="navToggler" class="container-fluid  TitleBG TitleHeight">
    <div id="navopener" class="Pointer" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:20%;bottom: calc(100% - 50px);background-color:transparent;"></div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <p class="navbar-brand WhiteText standardBtn Pointer">My&nbsp;Area</p>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-form navbar-right">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="txtQuickSearchV2" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search" />
      </div>
      <button id="btnQuickFind" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have the above `navbar` and when it re-sizes to mobile it kicks the 'Go' button and the search box to the line(s) below rather than aligning it right and keeping it in-line, which I'm assuming is that the navbar-right should be doing?

How do I keep them all in-line?

All the non-bootstrap classes are cosmetic (colour etc)

**EDIT:**

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/twqhop91/)

Comment: Make a fiddle so people can at least see what’s wrong.

Comment: @Strelok added one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design breaks at 768px - if you want to prevent this, you could overwrite the responsible bootstrap navbar CSS settings that use @media (min-width: 768px) just as I did in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ua0xbg17/1/

Below is the CSS that you need to add to your CSS file to overwrite the bootstrap settings. You will have to change the min-width of the container and navbar in this CSS to adapt it to your final navbar.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: left;
    }
    .container {
        min-width: 380px;
    }
    .navbar {
        border-radius: 4px;
        min-width: 380px;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .navbar-left {
        float: left !important;
    }
    .navbar-right {
        float: right !important;
    }
    .navbar-form .form-group {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .navbar-form .form-control {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .navbar-form {
        width: auto;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
                box-shadow: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
        margin-right: -15px;
    }
    .navbar-form.navbar-right:last-child {
        margin-right: -15px;
    }
    .navbar-text.navbar-right:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    } 
}
```